# Can't echo environment variables

Tags: batch-file

Can't seem to figure out where i'm going wrong here. I'm writing a script where I need to store a value for the next time in runs.

From the command line I try the following

```
setx -m test tesing
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved
echo %test%
```

returns

```
%test%
```

I have also tried this without -m and I can see the variables in the list in windows. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable will apply to new *processes* - launch a new cmd.exe and "echo %test%", observe the expected output. (Tested on Windows 7)

Comment: ah ok so this will do what I need it to then. thanks

Comment: This also means that A) scripts launched from within the terminal that performed setx may *not* see the new variable, but B) scripts launched by double-clicking *will* see the new variable.